# Next JS 13 On Demand Cache Revalidation from a remote ASP .NET Core backend

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, next.js, next.js13

I have a question about a use case of NextJS cache revalidation feature that I cant find anywhere.
For context, I am building a online food ordering platform where many restaurants (currently 30) can post their menus for the customer to order. Since there is 30 resturants and 500 customers per restaurant per day that requires many API calls so I introduced API caching on dynamic pages. Since the data on those pages changes mabye once or twice a month, it doesnt make sense to put the revalidation on a time period, but instead it should be on demand when data has been changed in the DB. Since I have a different React app for restaurant Admins I was wondering how can I **remotely revalidate data on my NextJS app through the .NET backend**.
The flow should go something like this:

`Admin changes data -> Backend updates data in DB -> Backend signals to all apps that the data has been changed -> NextJS app pulls new data on the next page visit.`

If you have any ideas or experience with these kinds of solution I would be eternally greatfull for any help.

Thank you in advance

I am looking for similar use cases everywhere or industry standards for large multi-tenant apps, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [revalidatePath](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath) or [revalidateTag](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidateTag) if you are using the fetch method.

The idea would be that you create an API endpoint that your .NET app posts to which triggers the revalidate. I'm actually trying to implement this now using a .NET app which watches for SQL Database Changes (I'll let you know how I go)